# Keep spaces in a url with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing an Excel macro to scrape data from a webpage our company uses. I have it working and it will take me to a URL, but I need to put GET data in the URL, and it has to have spaces. I can't figure out how to keep the spaces without them being converted to %20.

The GET data I'm trying to use is formatted like: Aug 23, 2018 (Thu)

```
theURL = theBeginning & "?startDate=" & chosenMonth & " " & chosenDay & ", 2018 (" & chosenDate & ")"
```

As of now, this is going to the browser as Aug%2023,%202018%20(Thu) and it's throwing an error on their website.

Comment: URLs cannot have spaces so what is the use if there is no such a URL?

Comment: The POST data uses spaces and doesn't function without it

Comment: POST data goes in the request body though, not in the URL.  The URL parameters are for the GET method

Comment: It's been 12 years since I've coded anything and apparently I've forgotten everything. What I need is to get thewebsite.com?startDate=Aug 23, 2018 (Thu) in the address bar and to navigate to it. The browser changes it to format properly. I want it to stop doing that. I'm currently exploring using javascript to decode my URI that was passed unencoded so I can get this to work.

Comment: Might help to show more than just one line of code

Comment: What else would you like to see? That's the relevant part but I'll be glad to share anything else you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's probably an easier way to do this, but I created this JavaScript

```
<form name = "myForm" method = "POST" action = "">
<input type = "text" name = "myURL" id = "myURL" />
</form>
<script>
t1 = window.setTimeout(function redirURL() { window.location = document.getElementById("myURL").value; },1000);
</script>
```

then passed my URL to it with this in VBA

```
Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
ieApp.Navigate "myJavaScriptPage.htm"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
With ieDoc.forms(0)
.myURL.Value = theURL
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
With ieDoc.forms(0)
.myURL.Value = theURL
```

I had to set a timeout of at least 1 second in the JavaScript or it would try to redirect before the VBA filled in the input box. I'm going to experiment with copying the URL to the clipboard and pasting to the address bar of IE, but this is working for me for now.